# Mathf.Clamp is messing with my camera movement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clamp

i am making a game that uses the WASD keys to move the camera between different objects and am using Mathf.Clamp to limit it but it now makes it so the movement doesn't work and i only move diagonal which shouldn't be possible without multiple key presses.

```
{
    public Vector3 startPos;
    public float moveDistance = 1;
    public float minX;
    public float minZ;
    public float maxX;
    public float maxZ;
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = startPos;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, moveDistance);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, -moveDistance);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(moveDistance, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-moveDistance, 0, 0);
        }

        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), transform.position.y, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minZ, maxZ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo and you meant `Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, minZ, maxZ)` instead of `Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minZ, maxZ)`

Answer (score 0):

looks like Ruzihm already answered your question.

I recently ran into some problems with Mathf.Clamp with negative numbers.
So I wanted to share the solution.
Cannot remember where I found it so sorry I can't credit the person who made it.

```
    public  float ClampAngle(float angle, float minAngle, float maxAngle)
{
    if (angle < 90 || angle > 270)
    {       // if angle in the critic region...
        if (angle > 180) angle -= 360;  // convert all angles to -180..+180
        if (maxAngle > 180) maxAngle -= 360;
        if (minAngle > 180) minAngle -= 360;
    }
    angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, minAngle, maxAngle);
    if (angle < 0) angle += 360;  // if angle negative, convert to 0..360
    return angle;
}
```